# SQLAlchemy object-layer cache

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlalchemy

I am switching my application from SQLObject to SQLAlchemy because its development and community are far more active.

The two ORMs are quite different. SQLObject doesn't have transactions and has its own cache. SQLAlchemy has a session cache, but it gets expired after session.commit. Turning on autocommit eliminates any cache.

The expiry of the cache after session.commit dramatically reduces performance.

I looked into dogpile caching, but it looks like it caches specific queries rather than objects. I'm looking for object-layer caching that persists after session.commit. That is, if I do order.Item, it should check the cache for order.ItemID and if it isn't in there, go to the database and add order.Item to the cache.

Edit:

I just discovered expire_on_commit flag:

```
    Session = sqlalchemy.orm.sessionmaker(bind=engine, expire_on_commit=False)
```

SQLAlchemy's creator said [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sqlalchemy/uYIawg4SUQQ):

> So, for a long time, all through 0.4, the default was, “never, and not even possible”.  There was no expire on commit, at that time I thought it was insane to throw away all that great data that you’ve loaded unless you absolutely want to.

With SQLObject I had the cache turned off so I'm already manually expiring objects. So turning off expire_on_commit should make the transition more natural.

Comment: first of all, why'd you turn on autocommit?

Comment: Just for experimentation.